# .NET Core - UseExceptionHandler method: Is this mainly targeted for Web Applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Does the method `UseExceptionHandler()` handle only HTTP Requests, in Controllers, or can they also handle exceptions which run as background services (tried that but didn't handle it)?
Otherwise, is there any other possible middleware which can possibly catch all global exceptions in the whole application?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the filter and middleware will only work for http request pipeline, a request is required otherwise the pipeline doesn't start. But the implementations of IHostedService are triggered by the Host.do not run within the request pipeline.

In my opinion, the right way is using try catch to capture the error and then use ilogger to log the exception is the best way.

`try{}catch(Exception e)`

More details, you could refer to this article to know more about exception [handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).